# How to make unsafe scripts load on my website

Tags: javascript, html

https://p17theo3.github.io/D3js-US-educational-attainment/newfolder/index1.html

this is my university project but for some reason google is blocking the scripts and they are marked unsafe. is there any possible way to fix this ?

Comment: you cannot load scripts from `http` when your site is running on `https` because everything in `https` site should come from `https` source. change all scripts to `https` if the cdn supports it . and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Your page shows a lot of errors like:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://p17theo3.github.io/D3js-US-educational-attainment/newfolder/index1.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

One way to resolve it is to load 3rd party scripts using HTTPS protocol e.g. in above switch from `http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js` to `https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP header Content-Security-Policy blocks the loading of the requested JS.
You can change this header by inserting into your HTML file (in the head tag)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' d3js.og ;  img-src data:; connect-src 'self'">
```

add more stuff as you need...

Comment: *"try this"* is not a useful explanation of your solution. Please explain what this does and why it is needed.